# Sticky.js changes the width of a DIV when position becomes "fixed"

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, sticky-footer

I have two container elements which variable widths.

http://maxwellrushton.com/buy-in-bleed-out/

Within one of them, the right one (currently coloured black to keep it obvious) there is a video. It is currently 100% of it's parent's width.

```
<div id="buy-in-video-container" class="container">

<iframe  class="buy-now-iframe" width="500" height="281" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mYNWY4tRWOo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div><!-- /#buy-invideo-container-->
```

with:

```
.page-id-511 #buy-in-video-container{
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
margin-top: 100px;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 1000px;
}

.buy-now-iframe{
width: inherit;
z-index: 1200;
position: relative;
}
```

I am using Sticky.js to hold the video in place when it's 200px from the top, as my client wants it to always be on the screen.

I can't specify the width as it varies, but I also can't specify the position as that varies too.

How on earth do I sort this, or do I have to specify a width further up the chain, but then lose the responsiveness in a bunch of media-query bollocks?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the answer was to surround the iframe with a div with the same css properties. Apparently the sticky.js doesn't appreciate dynamic content, such as the iframe, in the same way.